# Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: liquibase.Contexts.addAll(Ljava/util/Collection;) Liquibase updation throwing error

Tags: java, liquibase

I have updated my project to.
Liquibase 3.3.5.
And I am getting error as java.lang.NoSuchMethodError.

By seeing the class file of Contexts in both the version, I saw that liquibase 3.1.1 has extends as HashSet but 3.3.5 does not extends hashSet and hence addAll method is not found.

I cannot change the Context implementation as it is jar file coming from other project. How can I override the Context from liquibase 3.3.5 so as to keep it stable.

Answer (score 0):

How many times do you call the `contexts.addAll(..)` method ? 
Because if you call it only once and no `contexts.add()` you can use the constructor `Contexts(Collection<String> contexts)`

Comment: It is called once, but it is called as a part of bundled jar. I somehow have to override the contexts and add a new addAll method, I suppose.